# How to styling WPF button like in CSS attached example

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf

I try to get the look of the button like in css you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/763raf81/).
When you press this button it looks as if it goes inside.

Following is my `XAML` try, I used `DropShadowEffect`, but is not exactly like in css.

How can I achieve exactly look like in css?

Is it possible to translate CSS to XAML?

```xml
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="250" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                                    CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,6,0,-5" AllowDrop="True">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Reflect">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA8A8A8" Offset="0.923"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE0E0E0" Offset="0.391"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="Shadowborder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,10"
                                    CornerRadius="5">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border" Value="0,5,0,-5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shadowborder" Value="0,5,0,-5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="Shadowborder">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity="0.3" BlurRadius="1" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="20" Content="Hello!"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: "Is it possible to translate CSS to XAML?": yes. "How can I achieve exactly look like in css?" : customize default button's template which you have. @Bijan, answers are simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achieve exactly look like in CSS?

Yes, you only need to convert to XAML from CSS - by your brain.

Maybe it's a bit bloated, but it should be the most similar, welcome others to improve

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Padding="25,10"
        Content="Hello!"
        FontSize="36"
        FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                            Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BUTTON_FACE"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="0,4,0,4"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </ThicknessAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BUTTON_SHADOW"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                                                    To="2"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BUTTON_FACE"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="0,0,0,8"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                    </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </ThicknessAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BUTTON_SHADOW"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                                                    To="6"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="BUTTON_SHADOW"
                                        BlurRadius="6"
                                        Color="Gray"
                                        Direction="-90"
                                        ShadowDepth="6" />
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Border CornerRadius="0,0,10,10"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Height="18">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#DEDEDE"
                                            Offset="0.3" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#BEBEBE"
                                            Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#4E4E4E"
                                            Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Border Name="BUTTON_FACE"
                        Margin="0,0,0,8">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0"
                                            Color="White"
                                            Direction="90"
                                            ShadowDepth="1" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10"
                            Background="#E8E8E8">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1"
                                                Direction="-90"
                                                ShadowDepth="1"
                                                Color="White" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="10"
                                        RadiusY="10">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,2"
                                                            EndPoint="2,0"
                                                            MappingMode="Absolute"
                                                            SpreadMethod="Reflect">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.2" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD2D2D1"
                                                        Offset="0.2" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD2D2D1"
                                                        Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="10"
                                        RadiusY="10">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                            EndPoint="1,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.2" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="10"
                                        RadiusY="10">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                            EndPoint="1,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#4CD2D2D2"
                                                        Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00D2D2D2"
                                                        Offset="0.2" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00D2D2D2"
                                                        Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#4CD2D2D2"
                                                        Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="10"
                                        RadiusY="10">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0"
                                                            StartPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.5" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#4CFFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.5" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#33FFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border>
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0"
                                                        Direction="-90"
                                                        ShadowDepth="1"
                                                        Color="White" />
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                    Focusable="False"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                    RecognizesAccessKey="False"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0"
                                                            Direction="90"
                                                            ShadowDepth="1"
                                                            Color="#262F33" />
                                    </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image]

And it seem I've found something interesting.

Using CSS in XAML - XamlCSS

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67249/xamlcss-styling-xaml-applications-with-css